# How to call post from modified attachment page?

Tags: php, attachment

My post have more than one attachment, then i modified every the attachment page with content that i insert into db, but when i try to call that post it shows the parent post,

i try this one:

```
global $post;
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $parent = get_page($post->post_parent);
    $attc = apply_filters('the_content', $parent->post_content);
    echo $attc;
}
```

how to call the post_content from attachment db,? thanks

Comment: You probably want to get children page not parent? You can achieve that but using get_children() function, pass $post->ID as argument and see what it returns, that should be an array with children inside.

Comment: [edit] $ar = array(
     'order'          => 'ASC',
     'post_type'      => 'attachment',
     'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
     'post_mime_type' => 'image',
     'numberposts'    => -1,
   );
   $atts = get_children($ar); 

  foreach($atts as $att) {
   $atit   = $att->ID;
   $attcon = $att->post_content;
  }
  echo $attcon;

it can't,